# Sound icon is too wide Wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel, icons

Clicking on the space between keyboard language icon and sound icon there is showing sound widget. This indicates that the icon is too long.
I was trying to reinstall wingpanel.

[image: Sound icon is too wide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have disabled animations. Then GTK reserves the space for the revealer.